# Using prepared statements? I don't understand it at all

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been told this code is very susceptible to SQL injection. How do I change it to become secured? I know using prepared statements is the best but I haven't found a way that doesn't break it.

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$existsQuery = "select count(*) as count from entry where emailaddress like '" . $_POST[emailaddress] . "'";
$existsResult = mysqli_query($con, $existsQuery);

if ($existsResult->fetch_object()->count > 0) {
    header('Location: index2.php?email=exists');
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO entry (firstname, lastname, emailaddress, favoritesong) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[emailaddress]','$_POST[favoritesong]')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Honestly, just find yourself a good [PDO tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) and just get it to work. Then go back and apply what you've learned to your code. Understand it first, apply it second. Trying to both at the same time is difficult and can be overwhelming.

Comment: There are also a variety of MySQLi tutorials (like [this](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/44392-php-5-mysqli-prepared-statements/)) around

Comment: never trust client data ...thats all:)

Comment: Try this tutorial: [Avoiding the original mysql extension (part 1: mysqli)](http://phpmaster.com/avoid-the-original-mysql-extension-1/) and [(part 2: PDO)](http://phpmaster.com/avoid-the-original-mysql-extension-2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important point to avoid SQL-injection is, that you do not build your queries with string concatenation.

So instead of building the query like this...

```
$sql = "select count(*) from entry where emailaddress like '" . $_POST[emailaddress] . "'";
$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
```

...you would instead use binding. With binding, the ? placeholders will be replaced with the email address, but the database knows how to quote and how to escape the input...

```
$sql = 'select count(*) from entry where emailaddress like ?';
$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(1, $_POST[emailaddress], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

This parameterized queries work in PDO and in SQLi. A demonstration of how SQL-injection works you can see [here](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/hash_sqlinjection.php), just click the next arrow to fill in a bad user input.

There is one more thing to consider, the binding will give a certain protection from SQL-injection, but this should not prevent you from validating the user input. In your example this would mean, that you check whether the input is really an email address, otherwise just reject the user input.

Comment: Is this better or essentially the same thing? `$emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];` `$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO entry (firstname, lastname, emailaddress, favoritesong) VALUES ( :firstname, :lastname, :emailaddress, :favoritesong)');` `$stmt->bindParam(':emailaddress', $emailaddress, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: @AndrewBrigance - Yes, using named parameters does the same as the index 1 in the example, it's even more readable. Of course you need to bind the other variables (firstname, lastname and favoritesong) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape all variables that are passed to SQL, especially all $_POST and $_GET.

IMHO you can use PDO (examples of quoting: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php).

I hope that helps.

Comment: This is an answer of a question and as you see there is a link to the source which is PHP manual. The discussion about design patterns is an offtopic here.